# NodeJS use EJS can't get new html (query from MySQL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a problem in NodeJS when I use EJS.

I have 2 html pages. The first html page is for a user(client) to set a query range, and when they press the submit button, NodeJS will execute the SQL query, and response the query to second html.

My problem is: when I test the query, I can see the query in my console, but it just stops...

Here is my NodeJS code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var ejs = require("ejs");

app.set('views','./views');
app.set('views engine','ejs');

app.get('/graph4', function (req, res, next) {


var sql = `select A.card_id, A.state_id state,A.city_id city,A.mail,DATE_FORMAT(A.first_active_month,'%M %Y') first_active_month,B.score loyalty from users A left outer join loyalty B on A.card_id = B.card_id  where B.score between -10 and -9 limit 1`;   
var rows = [] 
fetchData(sql , function (rows) {               
    var now = new Date();
    var today = now.getFullYear() + "/" + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + now.getDate();
    console.log(rows)     
    res.render("graph4.ejs", {
        "title": "TEST",
        "today": today,
        "rows": rows
    })
    console.log("ejs end");
    }); 
});
```

And this is my EJS code:

```
<div style="text-align: center"> 
              <%- include("graph4.ejs",{"title": title , "today": today  }) %>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-heading table-datatable" id="ordersTable">
            <thead><tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Activate_Day</th>
            <th>loyalty</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% rows.forEach(function(row) {%>
              <tr>
                <td><%= row.card_id %></td>
                <td><%= row.state %></td>
                <td><%= row.city %></td>
                <td><%= row.mail %></td>
                <td><%= row.first_active_month %></td>
                <td><%= row.loyalty %></td>

              </tr>
                    <%});%>
           </tbody>
           </table>
```

When I run `app.js`, I got lots of errors like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQI3C.png)

And my second html(EJS) became like this (I just saw same error repeat and repeat):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfI58.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use names (variables) that don't describe the contents of the file, you made a mistake and attach the same file.

Do you see it?

```
res.render("graph4.ejs",

<%- include("graph4.ejs",
```

You try render `graph4.ejs` who include `graph4.ejs` who include `graph4.ejs` who include `graph4.ejs` who include `graph4.ejs`  ... until the include / memory limit is over.

Comment: Yes, I see it , but how to fix it?
I change my js file -->  `res.render("graph4",`

and...it had new error, it seems can't get new html(ejs)

Comment: @EdHsu Read the updated answer again. If you do not see the solution, take 2 deep breaths, take a short walk. You are inattentive, so I want you to find a solution yourself.

Comment: OK!!   I am trying to figure it out . Thanks a lot!!